# Not possible to create class assignment when educationClass created via Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

I created 2 `educationClass`:

- educationClass with description *Test100* created via Microsoft Graph
- educationClass with the description *Test* created by the Teams app.

The educationclass *Test100* is created using a `POST` to https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes with the following JSON object

```json
{
  "displayName": "Test100",
  "description": "Test100",
  "externalId": "3099",
  "mailNickName": "Test100-3099"
}
```

Teachers are added using a `POST` to
[https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/ID-Education-Class/teachers/$ref](https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/id-education-class/teachers/$ref) with the following JSON object

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/users/teacher-ID"
}
```

Members are added using a `POST` to
[https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/ID-Education-Class/members/$ref](https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/id-education-class/teachers/$ref) with the following JSON object

```
{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/users/ID-Member"
}
```

When I want to assign an assignment in the Teams app, it works fine with the educationClass created via Teams but not for the class created via Graph.

To me, it seems there is something missing in the Group properties for the educationClass created by Graph.

Response from `GET GROUP` for the class created by the API:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
  "id": "cd5a64f4-8784-4356-8c04-31deb1aa6849",
  "deletedDateTime": null,
  "classification": null,
  "createdDateTime": "2018-08-06T08:36:28Z",
  "creationOptions": [],
  "description": "Test100",
  "displayName": "Test100",
  "groupTypes": ["Unified"],
  "mail": "Test100-3099@wisad.be",
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "Test100-3099",
  "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
  "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
  "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
  "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
  "preferredDataLocation": null,
  "proxyAddresses": ["smtp:Test100-3099@mydomein", "SMTP:Test100-3099@mydomein"],
  "renewedDateTime": "2018-08-06T08:36:28Z",
  "resourceBehaviorOptions": [],
  "resourceProvisioningOptions": ["Team"],
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "HiddenMembership",
  "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_SyncSource_SectionId": "3099",
  "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_CreatedByUserId": "myuserid",
  "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_CreatedByAppId": "MyAppID",
  "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_ObjectType": "Section"
}
```

Response from `GET GROUP` for the class created in Teams:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/$metadata#groups/$entity",
  "id": "e971cfd4-dc4c-4321-ae51-4d216557bec8",
  "deletedDateTime": null,
  "classification": null,
  "createdDateTime": "2018-08-06T11:56:52Z",
  "creationOptions": ["classAssignments", "ExchangeProvisioningFlags:2509"],
  "description": "Test",
  "displayName": "Test",
  "groupTypes": ["Unified"],
  "mail": "Test92@mydomain",
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "Test92",
  "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
  "onPremisesProvisioningErrors": [],
  "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
  "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
  "preferredDataLocation": null,
  "proxyAddresses": ["smtp:Test92@mydomein.be", "SMTP:Test92@mydomain.be"],
  "renewedDateTime": "2018-08-06T11:56:52Z",
  "resourceBehaviorOptions": [
    "HideGroupInOutlook",
    "WelcomeEmailDisabled",
    "ConnectorsDisabled",
    "SubscribeNewGroupMembers"
  ],
  "resourceProvisioningOptions": [],
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "visibility": "HiddenMembership",
  "extension_fe2174665583431c953114ff7268b7b3_Education_ObjectType": "Section"
}
```

Notice that the `creationOptions` and `resourceBehaviorOptions` of the two Groups are different.

When I try to add a new assignment to education classes created by the GRAPH API, i get the following message saying: "Education class is being setup"

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a code sample showing how you're creating the Group in Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I updated the question a the top with code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to the send the Term startdate and enddate.

```
"term":{  
      "displayName":"Term2",
      "externalID":"2",
      "startDate":"2017-09-01",
      "endDate":"2019-08-31"
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your observations were spot on. The assignments Api (currently in Graph Beta) were not reading all the possible properties that could denote a class type. (creationOptions and another extension property which can be stamped to signal the group is a class type. Exactly which property get stamped is dependent on when the group was created and how).

We are working on a fix and getting it patched this week.
Thanks