# Assignment screen disabled for Teams created via Microsoft Graph

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-edu

When I create a Team (they are of the type Class for Teachers and Students) using the Microsoft Graph Education APIs, the Team appears in the Microsoft Teams app and the Assignment tab is visible.

When I try to create a new assignment in the Teams app, the screen for creating an assignment is disabled, so it's not possible to create new assignments for any Team created via the API.

Am I doing something wrong?

Team created through the API (controls are disabled, no save and delete controls):

[image]

Teams created through the Teams app (controls are enabled):

[image]

Workflow:

1. I create a Team via `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes`
   with the body of:

   ```
   {
     "displayName": "Test2",
     "description": "Test2",
     "classCode": "Test2",
     "externalId": "2",
     "externalName": "Test2",
     "externalSource": "sis",
     "mailNickName": "Test2_2",
     "term": {
       "displayName": "Term2",
       "externalID": "2",
       "startDate": "2017-09-01",
       "endDate": "2019-08-31"
     }
   }
   ```

   (also tried with `"externalSource":"manual"`)
2. Add a Teacher using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/{id}/teachers/$ref` with a body of

   ```
   {
     "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/users/{id}"
   }
   ```
3. Add a Student using `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/classes/{id}/members/$ref` with a body of:

   ```
   {
     "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/V1.0/education/users/{id}"
   }
   ```

All of these calls are successful and the Team shows up in the Teams app. The Assignment tab also shows up, so the Team is an Education Team.

Comment: This is due to the exact same reason as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708290/not-possible-to-create-class-assignment-when-educationclass-created-via-graph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not possible to create class assignment when educationClass created via Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708290/not-possible-to-create-class-assignment-when-educationclass-created-via-graph)

Answer (score 1):

This was a known bug - the fix was deployed on 9/3/2018.